# Como instalar swiper en Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, swiper

estoy tratando de instalar swiper en vue, pero he tenido problemas con las importaciones, este es el log que me lanza:

```
These dependencies were not found:

* swiper/css in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* swiper/vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install them, you can run: npm install --save swiper/css swiper/vue
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
```

Este es mi archivo App.vue que esta casi como lo muestra la documentación, es lo único que he modificado en este proyecto, lo demás esta por default a como se crea el proyecto de vue.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <swiper :slides-per-view="3" :space-between="50" @swiper="onSwiper" @slideChange="onSlideChange">
      <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    </swiper>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// Import Swiper Vue.js components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
  setup() {
    const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
      console.log(swiper);
    };
    const onSlideChange = () => {
      console.log('slide change');
    };
    return {
      onSwiper,
      onSlideChange,
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

Estas son las versiones de mis dependencias que tengo instaladas en mi proyecto:

```
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"swiper": "^7.3.1",
"vue": "^2.6.11"
```

Ya he intentado bajar la versión de swiper, e ingresar el comando `npm install --save swiper/css swiper/vue` que me lanza el log, pero no me ha funcionado.

Comment: Hmm... ¿Funciona Swiper 7 con Vue 2?

Comment: La verdad no se, no encontre en la documentacion temas de compatibilidad, pero trate de bajar la versión de swiper al 6 o de actualizar a vue 3 y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Solo por probar: ¿ya intentaste limpiar la caché de npm?

Comment: Acobo de probar con npm cache clean --force pero sigue lanzando el mismo log

Comment: Hay un [issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/5178) similar al tuyo, que a su vez lo vincularon a [este issue pineado en la repo](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4871). ¿Llegaste a intentar lo mencionado en la guía que pusieron a disposición?

Comment: Actualice vue a la versión 3.2.23, tambien introduje las importaciones directas que mencionan [aquí](https://swiperjs.com/react#usage-with-create-react-app), con esto ahora me lanza:
`Failed to resolve loader: sass-loader
You may need to install it.`
Pero al intentar instalar sass-loader me lanza otro log mucho mas largo
`npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack`

Comment: Imagino que tenés una versión de [npm >= 7](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major), ¿probaste instalar sass-loader con la opción `--legacy-peer-deps`?

Comment: Bien, ya pude instalarlo con ese comando, pero ahora me lanza esto:
`Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'`

Busque una solución y por el momento trate de desinstalar node_modules e instalarlo, tambien limpiar cache, pero no ha funcionado.

Comment: _Nunca es tarde_: ¿llegaste a resolver los conflictos? ¿Ejecutaste `npm update vue-template-compiler`, como se indica en este [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1741#issuecomment-822296160)? (O instalarlo). No olvides que la versión de `vue-template-compiler` debe ser la misma que la de `vue`.